# Maintaining two different versions of the same git repo without splitting into two branches

Tags: git, branch

Probably a silly question, but I'm trying to figure out if this is possible and, if it is, the best approach for it. I have two different sets of source code for the same repo due to the need to build this repo on two different operating systems. A good majority of the source is shared mutually, but there are bits of it that differ between the two. Is there a way to store this information in git without having to maintain two repos/branches in parallel? I need to be able to tag the repo as a whole, which cannot be done if there are multiple branches.

Comment: Why won't you have both sources in the same codebase and have a logic to decide with code to run based on the OS it's running on? For me, that seems the appropriate way of approaching this kind of setting. May be include some details about the technologies you are using to get advice tailored to your project.